# How to route any extension with asp.net 4 routing?

Tags: asp.net, .net-4.0, asp.net-4.0, whois

I'm trying to handle domain requests like [whois.innovacube.com/anydomain.com](http://whois.innovacube.com/anydomain.com) like [whois.domaintools.com/stackoverflow.com](http://whois.domaintools.com/stackoverflow.com)

My global.asax file contains code below and it handles requests like /test :

```
<%@ Application Language="C#" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="System.Web.Routing" %>

<script runat="server">    
    void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.Ignore("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}"); // ignore web resources etc

        routes.MapPageRoute("domain", "{domain}", "~/default.aspx");
    }
    void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
    }
</script>
```

Comment: What IIS version are you using?

Comment: IIS 7.5 on Windows Server 2008 web

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've solved problem by creating web.config file and adding lines below:

```
<system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
</system.webServer>
```

Answer (score 0):

did you try this

```
routes.MapPageRoute("domain", "{*domain}", "~/default.aspx");
```

it should catch all